# How to pass empty list with type parameter?

Tags: java, list, generics, collections

```
class User{
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public User(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Service<T> {
    private List<T> data;
    public void setData(List<T> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class ServiceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Service<User> result=new Service<User>();
        result.setData(Collections.emptyList()); // problem is here
    }
}
```

How to pass empty list with type parameter?

compiler giving me error message:

> The method setData(List< User > ) in the type Service is not
>   applicable for the arguments (List< Object > )

and if I try to cast with List then the error:

> Cannot cast from List< Object > to List< User >

`result.setData(new ArrayList<User>());` is working fine but I don't want to pass it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`Collections.emptyList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList()) is generic, but you're using it in its raw version.

You can explicitly set the type-parameter with:

```
result.setData(Collections.<User>emptyList());
```

Answer (score 6):

simply
 `result.setData(Collections.<User>emptyList());`

Answer (score 0):

> The issue you're encountering is that even though the method
>   emptyList() returns List, you haven't provided it with the type, so
>   it defaults to returning List. You can supply the type
>   parameter, and have your code behave as expected, like this:

```
  result.setData(Collections.<User>emptyList());
```

> Now when you're doing straight assignment, the compiler can figure out
>   the generic type parameters for you. It's called type inference. For
>   example, if you did this:

```
 List<User> emptyList = Collections.emptyList();
```

> then the emptyList() call would correctly return a List.